# python | Tkinter RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, qthread

The code works properly, but sometimes returns RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
I tried to solve this error for three days, but I couldn't.
I am currently using QThread.

```
            class MultyThread(QThread):
            
                def __init__(self, main):
                    super().__init__(main)
                    a = open("geometry.txt","r")
                    self.a1 = a.readline()
                    a.close()
            
                    n = open("size.txt","r")
                    self.n1 = str(n.readline())
                    n.close()
            
                def run(self):
```

error spot

> label3 = mtTkinter.Label(text=' ', font=('Gulim', self.n1, "bold", "bold"), fg='gray80')

```
                    label3.master.overrideredirect(True)
                    label3.master.geometry(self.a1)
                    label3.master.lift()
                    label3.master.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
                    label3.master.wm_attributes("-disabled", True)
                    label3.master.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", label3.master['bg'])
                    hWindow = pywintypes.HANDLE(int(label3.master.frame(), 16))
                    exStyle = win32con.WS_EX_COMPOSITED | win32con.WS_EX_LAYERED | win32con.WS_EX_NOACTIVATE | win32con.WS_EX_TOPMOST | win32con.WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
                    win32api.SetWindowLong(hWindow, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE, exStyle)
                    label3.pack()
                    label3.update()
                    while True:
        ...
        
        class MyApp(QWidget):
        
            def __init__(self):
                super().__init__()
                self.initUI()
    ...
        
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            app = QApplication(sys.argv)
            ex = MyApp()
            sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. You make us guess.

Comment: Why do you use both `QT` and `tkinter` in same application? Use either one.